# Oracle APEX 5 main page not loading properly

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I'm getting this message in the browser after I install Oracle APEX 5.1.0:

> There is a problem with your environment because the Application
>   Express files have not been loaded. Please verify that you have copied
>   the images directory to your application server as instructed in the
>   Installation Guide. In addition, please verify that your image prefix
>   path is correct. Your current path is /i/ (it should contain both
>   starting and ending forward slashes, such as the default /i/). Use the
>   SQL script reset_image_prefix.sql if you need to change it.

I'm following [this instruction](http://o7planning.org/en/10341/installing-and-configuring-oracle-apex). I'm running this instruction on Linux Fedora 23, my Oracle APEX images folder is located in `/home/oracle/apex/apex/images`.

Comment: my linux apex install has my images here: /u01/app/oracle/apex
Note that there is no second apex directory. I would uninstall apex and try again. 
I would also need to see your dir structures and the commands you run and where you run them from. also, this might help:https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/oracle-application-express-apex-5-0-installation

Comment: thanks Joe ...I'm still working and researching about the problem ...that's where I unziped  the apex 5.1 file `/home/oracle/apex
`  I run all the commands inside the apex folder from my Fedora Linux like this `sqlplus '/as sysdba'`  the current installed apex version at my oracle is `3.2.1.00.10
`

Comment: You have to install the images as described in the install procedure using the directory one level up the unzipped apex folder. At least that worked for me.

Comment: right now I'm using this guide it much better https://tekslate.com/tutorials/oracle-apex/ ...but still one thing I don't understand is how to copy the images to my Oracle Http server where is that is located `cp -R /tmp/apex/images $FR_INST/config/OHS/ohs1/htdocs/apex_images` and this one too `Alias /i/ "/u01/app/oracle/middleware/FR_inst/config/OHS/ohs1/htdocs/apex_images/"`?  I think once I have the images into my oracle server the issue will be solved but I don't know where to put it  .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it by going to `/home/oracle/apex/utilities` and then `sqlplus '/as sysdba'` and run the command `@reset_image_prefix.sql` .